# Connection failed - Activation of network connection failed

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, connection

I have a Dell Inspiron laptop running Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS.
The system has always connected to my home WiFi automatically on start without any problems.
Since two days ago every time I start the system I get the above error i.e. Connection failed - Activation of network connection failed and the system cannot connect to the WiFi.
I fixed it a couple of times forgetting the network and reconnecting inputting the password but every time I restart the system I get the error again and forgetting the network does not work anymore. The last time I managed to reconnect I also run a dist upgrade and apt get just in case.
Rooter and WiFi work perfectly on the other devices i.e. laptops, phones, TV,etc.
Any idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and `dpkg -l wpasupplicant`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Answer (score 0):

Today other devices started failing to connect so I rebooted the router and that solved the problem.

Apologies I should have tried that before posting my question. Thank you for the help anyway.