# I can see WiFi networks available around, but can't login

Tags: wireless, 20.04, network-manager

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.2. I can see WiFi networks available around, but when trying to login open or locked networks, the answer is:

> Activation of network connection failed.

I tried `sudo service network-manager restart` - no result. And switch off power management for WiFi - no changes.
Any idea what can be done to fix the issue?

`iwconfig` answer:

```
lo no wireless extensions.
enp19s0 no wireless extensions.

wlp18s0 IEEE 802.11 ESSID:off/any
Mode:Managed Access Point: Not-Associated Tx-Power=14 dBm
Retry short limit:7 RTS thr:off Fragment thr:off Power Management:off
```

Update 6.09.21
Downloaded ISO Ubuntu to virtual drive, checked the the “CDrom with [your distro name and version] box”  but no additional drivers was found.

Comment: Try using these commands to restart network manager https://tecadmin.net/restart-network-on-ubuntu-20-04/.  I'm not sure if you actually restarted the service

Comment: I just tried your way and no changes. Any idea how I can test the problem?

Comment: I just found this article https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-wi-fi-not-working-ubuntu/ and one other: there are additional links which may help test the issue : https://itsfoss.com/fix-no-wireless-network-ubuntu/.  https://appuals.com/activation-of-network-connection-failed-in-linux/ See what you can do with these

Comment: also refer here for more troubleshooting tips on your pc: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1338270/connection-failed-activation-of-network-connection-failed

Comment: If you still can't fix this, post the output from this link along with all the steps you have taken.   https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Be sure to hit the edit button beneath the question and post all updates there.  The comments section is designed only for brief text and links.

Answer (score 0):

it's come out it was very specific problem - so, maybe not much help for others.
I replaced the wifi module in the laptop and strait away I could login to all networks